# VBA: Change cell value based on approximate values of other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling on a piece of VBA that I've written whose purpose would be to change the value of a cell in column B if column G contains certain bits of text. Here's what I've written so far:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Sheets("Current Week").Select
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Eagle*" Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = "Bird"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Though the above works, I'm struggling is that I'd like to add more "Values like" than just "Eagle". I've tried the following without much success:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Sheets("Current Week").Select
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Eagle*" 
        Or ("G" & i).Value Like "*Pelican*"
        Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "Bird"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

How do I add more "Values like"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from VB(A)'s requirement of using a [line continuation character](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141513) (`_`) if you want to break a line up for readability purposes.

```
' ...

If _
    Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Eagle*" Or _
    Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Pelican*" Or _
    Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Chicken*" Or _
    Range("G" & i).Value Like "*Sparrow*" _
Then
    Range("G" & i).Value = "Bird"
End If

' ...
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct (also, I was missing a "Next" statement). I've corrected it. Thanks so much!